# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - JavaScript - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

And this is my JavaScript / jQuery Code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".menu-toggle").hover(function() {
    $("#Wrapper").css("transform", "perspective(900px) rotateY(-5deg)")
  };
  }, function() {
    $("#Wrapper").css("transform", "perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg)")
  };
});
});
```

Thank you very many for your help!

Comment: I have formatted the code correctly now, so hopefully it should be much easier for you to spot the problem. I would strongly suggest you use an IDE with a built in syntax highlighter and a linter. It makes it almost impossible to make these kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

`.hover()` can take **two** functions. Your syntax is incorrect because you are using `;` instead of `,`.

Remove the `;` and replace with a `,` as per the jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/). Also replace `});` with `);` at the bottom.

I've formatted to make it easier to read.

```js
$(".menu-toggle").hover(
  function() {
    $("#Wrapper").css("transform", "perspective(900px) rotateY(-5deg)");
  }, 
  function() {
    $("#Wrapper").css("transform", "perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg)");
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you steadweb, now runs perfect!